# Puppeteer crashes 'Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at'

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a NodeJS script using puppeteer to download few hundred thousand documents from a website. And Each file takes about 1.5s to get the download link. Due to high download count, and because of that massive amount of time it takes, I thought it would be a good idea to download multiple at a time.

So my idea was to open the list of pages the files contains using main.js, and send batches of x files to x child processes then open each in a new browser and then to download. (Due to the nature of this website, they don't have a direct download path, it generates the path on the process. So plugging download url directly is not an option.)

main

```
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');
const fork = require('child_process').fork;

var zip = require ('./zip_files');
var fld = require('./create_folders');
var log = require('./login');

var ls = [];

const docType = ['pdf', 'word', 'spreadsheet'];
const docExt = ['.pdf', '.docx', '.xlsx'];

const login_url = 'https://www.scribd.com/login';
const login_email = '';
const login_password = '';

const t_out = 10000;
/*
Link Format

https://www.scribd.com/search?query=Exporters+in+Andra+Pradesh&content_type=documents&page=1&filetype=pdf
*/

var pages=[];

const datasetF1 = 'wordset_11.csv';
const datasetF2 = 'wordset_22.csv';

var data_1 = [];
var data_2 = [];

var fileCount = 1000000;

data_1 = fs.readFileSync(datasetF1).toString().split(',');
data_2 = fs.readFileSync(datasetF2).toString().split(',');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(({
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: path.join(__dirname,'user_data/main'),
    }));
    console.log(browser) 
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    
    //await log.login(page, login_url, login_email, login_password, t_out);
    
    child();

    //await page.goto('https://www.scribd.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    for(let i = 0; i < data_1.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < data_2.length; j++){
            let folder = data_1[i].replace(/\n/gm, '').replace(/\r/gm, '') + ' ' + data_2[j].replace(/\n/gm, '').replace(/\r/gm, '');
            let searchTerm = data_1[i].replace(/\n/gm, '').replace(/\r/gm, '') + ' ' + data_2[j].replace(/\n/gm, '').replace(/\r/gm, '');
            for(let pageNum = 1; pageNum < (Math.ceil(fileCount/42) +1) && pageNum < 236; pageNum++){
                //maxPageNum = 235
                let docType = 'pdf';
                let query = 'https://www.scribd.com/search?query='+searchTerm+'&content_type=documents&page='+pageNum+'&filetype='+docType;
                
                console.log(pageNum);
            
                await page.goto(query, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
                
                fs.appendFileSync('progress/query.txt', query + '\n');
                if (pageNum == 1){
                    await page.waitForXPath('//div[@class="_7a1igU"]', { timeout: t_out }).then(async() => {
                        let fileCountR = await page.$x('//div[@class="_7a1igU"]');
                        let fileCountS = await (await fileCountR[0].getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
                        var fileCount = parseInt(fileCountS.split('of ').pop().split(' results').shift().replace(/,/g, ''));
                        console.log(fileCount);
                    }).catch( e => { 
                        console.log('ERROR1');
                        console.log(e);
                //console.log(e);
                    });
                }
                
                await page.waitForXPath('//section[@data-testid="search-results"]', { timeout: t_out }).then(async() => {
                    let searchResults = await page.$x('//section[@data-testid="search-results"]');
                    await searchResults[0].waitForXPath('//div/ul/li');
                    let docPages = await searchResults[0].$x('//div/ul/li');
                    
                    await download(browser, /*page,*/ docPages, folder);
                }).catch( e => { 
                    console.log('ERROR2');
                    console.log(e);
                }); 
            
            }
            //await zip.zipFolder(down_path + folder, zip_path + folder + '.zip');
        }
    }
    //browser.close();
})();


async function child(){
    for(let a = 0; a < 3; a++){
            ls[a] = fork('download.js');
    }
}


async function download(browser, docPages, folder){
    let child_count = 3;

    const paged = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        for(let b = 0; b < docPages.length; b+=child_count){
            await send_data(browser, docPages, folder, child_count, b);
            console.log("b : b");
        }
    });
}
async function send_data(browser, docPages, folder, child_count, b){
    let c = 0;
    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        for(let a = 0; a < child_count; a++){
            let urlR = await docPages[a+b].$x('//article/a');
            let url = await (await urlR[0].getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
                    
            fs.appendFileSync('progress/page.txt', url + '\n');
            ls[a].on('message', (msg) => {
                if(msg == 'Executed'){

                }if(msg == 'done'){
                    c++
                    if(c == (child_count-1)){
                        resolve({});
                    }
                }
            });
            ls[a].send([url, folder, a]);
            
        }
    });
}
```

child (download.js)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
const down_path = 'downloads/';
const error_path = 'errors/';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
var log = require('./login');

const login_url = 'https://www.scribd.com/login';
const login_email = '';
const login_password = '';

const t_out = 1000;

const dowload_errorFile = 'errors.txt';

var browser;
var flag = 0;

const t_outforL = 100000;

process.on('message', async (obj)=> {
    console.log("CHILD: data received from parent process", obj);
    console.log("Process Starting : ", process.pid);
    
    url = obj[0];
    loc = obj[1];
    ins = obj[2];
    
    if(!flag){
        browser = await puppeteer.launch(({
            headless: false,
            userDataDir: path.join(__dirname,'user_data/'+ins),
        }));
        const downPage = (await browser.pages())[0];
        await downPage.goto('https://www.scribd.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        flag = 1;
    }
    await download(url, loc);
});
process.send('Executed');

async function download(url, folder){
        const downPage = (await browser.pages())[0];
        await downPage.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        await downPage.waitForXPath('//button[@data-e2e="download-button"]', { timeout: 1000 }).then(async ()=>{
            let dwnld = await downPage.$x('//button[@data-e2e="download-button"]');
            const client = await downPage.target().createCDPSession()
            await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
                behavior: 'allow',
                downloadPath: path.join(__dirname, 'downloads/' + folder),
            })
            await dwnld[0].click();
        
            await downPage.waitForXPath('//a[@class="wrapper__filled-button download_selection_btn"]');
            let clicks = await downPage.$x('//a[@class="wrapper__filled-button download_selection_btn"]');
            await clicks[0].click();
            await downPage.waitForTimeout(500);
            process.send('done');
        }).catch( e => { 
            console.log('No download exists');
            console.log(e);
        });
        await downPage.waitForTimeout(2500);
        //process.exit();
}
```

It runs perfectly fine for a round or 2, but then puppeteer crashes with

```
Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://www.scribd.com/document/456861933
    at navigate (D:\Projects\Upwork\Project 6 (Rustom Vazifdar)\code\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Frame.js:238:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Frame.goto (D:\Projects\Upwork\Project 6 (Rustom Vazifdar)\code\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Frame.js:207:21)
    at async CDPPage.goto (D:\Projects\Upwork\Project 6 (Rustom Vazifdar)\code\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:439:16)
    at async download (D:\Projects\Upwork\Project 6 (Rustom Vazifdar)\code\download.js:59:3)
    at async process.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Upwork\Project 6 (Rustom Vazifdar)\code\download.js:53:2)
```

Comment: Puppeteer pages already run in child processes. Have you tried [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster)? If you add more details about the actual task, it'd be easier to make a more detailed recommendation. Often, there are optimization avenues you may not have considered.

Comment: @ggorlen edited the question with all information

Comment: @ggorlen is there a way to add a user-data directory for puppeteer-cluster? this website has a signin page, I cannot do it over and over so I need to login and save it for later use

Comment: See [`puppeteerOptions`](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#clusterlaunchoptions) which lets you pass whatever you want to `puppeteer.launch`.

Comment: Thank it works... I'll share the solution in few days, I searched all over for a solution but didn't found one. Someone with the same problem can may get an answer then.

Comment: @LittleMAN can you share the solution? I have the same problem and can not find any help on the web.